# Установка фокуса ввода в pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, focus

Требуется установить фокус ввода на конкретный виджет, пытаюсь это сделать при помощи метода setFocus, но результата нет, в чем может быть проблема?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
lineedit2.setFocus()
button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('t&ext')
vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(lineedit1)
vbox.addWidget(lineedit2)
vbox.addWidget(button1)
window.setLayout(vbox)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

или при создании объекта  `lineedit` добавьте родителя.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('lineedit1', window)           # <--- , window
lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('lineedit2', window)           # <--- , window
lineedit2.setFocus()

button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('t&ext')

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(lineedit1)
vbox.addWidget(lineedit2)
vbox.addWidget(button1)
window.setLayout(vbox)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте установить фокус после добавления виджетов на форму:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('t&ext')
vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(lineedit1)
vbox.addWidget(lineedit2)
vbox.addWidget(button1)
window.setLayout(vbox)
lineedit2.setFocus()                # <<<<<<<<<<<<
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```